# How to terminate an EMR Cluster from Lambda when all Steps are COMPLETE?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I am trying to figure out how I can terminate an EMR cluster successfully once all the steps submitted to it are `'COMPLETED'|'CANCELLED'|'FAILED'|'INTERRUPTED'`. There are three Lambda functions.

- Lambda 1: Does some work and creates EMR. Triggers Lambda 2 by passing steps and cluster ID through event.
- Lambda 2: Submits the steps received from Lambda 1 to the cluster ID received from the same.
- Lambda 3: Submits a final step and then should send a request for termination when all steps are `'COMPLETED'|'CANCELLED'|'FAILED'|'INTERRUPTED'`.

I've done till Lambda 3's step submission, but unable to do the rest.

I have successfully created EMR through:

```
conn = boto3.client("emr")
cluster_id = conn.run_job_flow()
```

submitted steps through:

```
conn = boto3.client("emr")
action = conn.add_job_flow_steps(JobFlowId=cluster_id, Steps=event["steps"])
```

Now how can this termination be triggered only on the given condition? I saw the [boto3 API doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.add_job_flow_steps) which has `client.terminate_job_flows()`, but this function doesn't wait for the steps to finish or fail and directly hits the termination process.

Is there a way to change `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` from `TRUE` to `FALSE` when all my steps are done? Then I think it should automatically turn off the cluster. But going by the API docs, didn't find any option to change this parameter once the `run_job_flow()` is called.

Hope I was able to convey the issue I faced correctly. Any help?

Note: Using Python 3.8 in AWS Lambda. Each steps are Spark jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your research. The optimal situation would be to set `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` to `FALSE` to have the cluster self-terminate.

I do notice that the [RunJobFlow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html) documentation says:

> If the `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` parameter is set to `TRUE`, the cluster transitions to the `WAITING` state rather than shutting down after the steps have completed.

Therefore, the Lambda function could check whether the cluster is in the `WAITING` state and, if so, shutdown the cluster. However, this would take repeated checking.

It *might* be possible to submit a final step that calls the EMR API to shutdown the cluster. This means that the cluster is effectively calling for its own termination as a final step. (I haven't tried this concept, but it would be a clean way of performing the shutdown without having to repeatedly check the status.)

There is also a similar discussion about shutting down idle clusters on this Question: [How to terminate AWS EMR Cluster automatically after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49806543/174777)

Comment: Hi @John, you've been my AWS saviour for more than a year now, thanks for that. I was thinking through the similar lines of your second last paragraph which will submit a final step to self terminate the EMR, but no luck finding a set of step arguments/parameters for the same. Also checked your other answer but the isIdle Boolean seems to be deprecated. Please let me know if there's a way to crack this.

Comment: [Monitor Metrics with CloudWatch - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics.html) makes several references to the `isIdle` metric. I couldn't see any indication that it is deprecated.

Comment: Here's another sneaky idea... I notice that when calling `add_job_flow_steps()`, there is a parameter `'ActionOnFailure': 'TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW'|'TERMINATE_CLUSTER'`. I wonder if you could add an intentionally-bad step, and then tell it to `TERMINATE_CLUSTER` on failure?

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome idea. Anyway, I've built a solution already which is running as expected. Shall post an answer with the code, here.